# How to detect null default value for non-typed class property via reflection in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection, php-8

When using reflection (`ReflectionClass`), is it possible to detect, whether a non-typed class property has a `null` default value specified, or has no default value at all?

```php
class A {
    public $foo;
    public $bar = null;
}
```

Here, for both `foo` and `bar`, the `ReflectionProperty::getDefaultValue()` returns `null` and `ReflectionProperty::hasDefaultValue()` returns `true`.

```php
$rc = new ReflectionClass(A::class);
var_dump($rc->getProperty("foo")->hasDefaultValue()); // true
var_dump($rc->getProperty("foo")->getDefaultValue()); // null
var_dump($rc->getProperty("bar")->hasDefaultValue()); // true
var_dump($rc->getProperty("bar")->getDefaultValue()); // null
```

How can I differentiate between the two properties?

Comment: You can't, because these two properties are strictly identical. You can avoid this by not using untyped properties. `public mixed $foo;` and `public mixed $foo = null;` are different properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since php 7.4, class properties have an uninitialized state. This state is not the same as null:

```php
class A {
    public string $foo;
}

$a = new A();
var_dump($a->foo === null);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property A::$foo must not be accessed before initialization in ...

However, if there is no type declared the property will have null as its uninitialized value:

```php
class B {
    public $foo;
}

$b = new B();
var_dump($b->foo === null); // true
```

You can use [ReflectionProperty::isInitialized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.isinitialized.php) to check whether a property is initialized and [ReflectionProperty::hasType](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.hastype.php) to check if it has a type.

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_vars()` should allow to make the difference

The documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php
says

> Uninitialized properties are considered inaccessible, and thus will not be included in the array.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. `get_object_vars()` returns `["a" => null, "b" => null]`.

Comment: Aha, probably because, as @Enrico Dias says, If there is no type declared the property will have null as its uninitialized value: